# Assembly Errors in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly

I believe I am using the most recent version of Visual Studio. And I am running into some problems when I run my code. I set up an empty project and fill it with a main method, and an extern to an assembly file:

```
#include <stdio>
extern "C" {
  int Func();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  printf("%d\n", Func());
  return 0;
}
```

And the assembly file:

```
.model small
.stack
.data
.code
_Func proc
  mov eax, 0
  ret
_Func endp
end
```

When I run the file I get a weird error, it has a popup: "Assembly.exe has triggered a breakpoint." When I didn't trigger one, then when I hit break, it's in some weird "crtexe.c" file that I don't know about on line 626:

```
mainret = main(argc, argv, envp);
```

If you have any suggestions... That'd be great. I also still have the stupid cannot open PDB file errors...

I have already set build deps to use masm, so that isn't the problem.
I have seen this problem a lot around other sites, but they have no useful information.

Comment: `Fun` and `Func` are different functions.

Comment: @Ajay Yeah, sorry, that's a typo. Other help is appreciated